# Correct Plugin File Path

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, paths

> **Warning**:  require_once(/assets/MCAPI.class.php): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   **/home2/....../wp-content/plugins/bplugin/shortcodes.php** on line
>   **148**
>  
>  **Fatal error**:  require_once(): Failed
>   opening required '/assets/MCAPI.class.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/php54/lib/php') in
>   **/......./wp-content/plugins/bplugin/shortcodes.php** on line
>   **148**

```
require_once(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/assets/MCAPI.class.php');
```

Am I not using the **correct path method**?

This file is called inside a rest API function →
https://www.screencast.com/t/5mhWur8hmR

Update: If I transfer file from assets to the plugin directory then things work →

```
require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'MCAPI.class.php');
```

but that's not the very clean method of handling files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/

It looks like this function adds a trailing slash, so starting your string with a slash is not required try;

```
require_once(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/MCAPI.class.php');
```

Comment: I tried the one you suggested, but that generates the error →

Comment: Oh God assets was written as assests

Comment: It was my silly mistake. does this question make any sense? or should I delete the question?

Comment: Lol I think just leave it for that comment. 'assests'